# Match 2 SQL columns in same table then set value to new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to update a column if 2 other columns match?

Table1:

| USER | PCID | PCID2 | LEVEL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hurry | 0 | 88817 | 5 |
| wilson | 88817 | 0 | 0 |
| dizon | 55827 | 0 | 4 |
| alex | 41937 | 0 | 2 |

I tried this query but it updates even if 2 column are not match.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET LEVEL = (SELECT LEVEL FROM Table1 WHERE PCID = PCID2)
WHERE USER = wilson
```

OUTPUT should be, first its must match the value of PCID to PCID2 then if they are match COPY the VALUE of LEVEL from PCID2 to LEVEL of PCID of USER stated in WHERE.

Result must be like this:

| USER | PCID | PCID2 | LEVEL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hurry | 0 | 88817 | 5 |
| wilson | 88817 | 0 | 5 |

Thanks for the help and replies.

Comment: please provide the desired output

Comment: What happens if you have more than 1 row where your PCID and PCID2 matches?

Comment: And what do you want to happen when there is no match? And why do you show user 'hurry' in your output? That shouldn't be updated?

Comment: if PCID2 detects more than 1 PCID in other rows it also get the value of 5 since my source is PCID2.

Comment: Your results are not reproducible see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=60da529a020c15263ce65d1885d7d002). But then your query has syntax errors, so it seems you haven't tested it.

Comment: if you have more than 1 PCID2 what happen?

Comment: IF no patch or value of PCID & PCID2 is not same then nothings update or value stay 0 or what ever is the default value of LEVEL

Comment: if i have more than 1 PCID with same value, LEVEL value is same. (i already manage that.)

Comment: MY only problem is i need to update LEVEL of other user if they are same PCID & PCID2

Comment: So what should `wilson 22548` end up as after your update?

Comment: if PCID2(88817) of hurry is same with PICD(88817) of willson, then update LEVEL of wilson  put LEVEL(5) from  hurry LEVEL(5).

Comment: I asked about the second wilson, which will get updated due to your where clause. As there is no match, what should the new level be?

Comment: if no match then nothing change to its LEVEL

Comment: Be good if you could [edit] your question and clarify all the issues people have raised.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of issues with your query, not least is that as provided it has syntax errors - which I assume arise from oversimplification of the problem.

The key issue is that you are not correlating the subquery with your outer table, so `(SELECT LEVEL FROM Table1 WHERE PCID = PCID2)` becomes a compare of the 2 columns in the subquery from an arbitrary row with no correlation to the outer query. Using table aliases, and table prefixing your columns is the way to get around this.

The second point is you are not testing whether a match is found or not, so originally you were actually setting the second "wilson" (22548) to 'NULL'.

I have used a `CROSS APPLY` for the sub-query to avoid repeating it in the `CASE` expression.

```
UPDATE T1 SET
    -- Best add a top 1 in case there are multiple matches
    [LEVEL] = CASE WHEN X.[LEVEL] IS NOT NULL THEN X.[LEVEL] ELSE T1.[LEVEL] END
FROM MyTable T1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 T2.[LEVEL] FROM MyTable T2 WHERE T2.PCID2 = T1.PCID) X ([LEVEL])
WHERE [USER] = 'wilson';
```

Note I would also recommend against using reserved words like `USER` as you are constantly having to escape them.

Comment: I see, so thats why people are confuse, i did not see the wilson name is duplicate its my typo error , sorry for that guys.

Comment: sorry late reply. i still not figured it out, im trying to separate into other table now so maybe i can match this thing.

Comment: @MarkovSeñoritoGuerrero my answer works for the sample data you have provided? What isn't working for you?